# Docker: Is it possible to mount a path from a different image into a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

we have the situation, that there are files in a docker image (yes, not volume!)
and we want it to mount them in a container. The f6c1a62a47a2 is the "Image ID".

```
docker run -it --rm  -v f6c1a62a47a2:/target/path busybox
```

This command throws no errors but the content of the image is not mounted to  /target/path
in the resulting container. The mount can be readonly. We do not want to change something.
Is this possible or only with volumes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to share it via the host and map either a host path or a docker volume into both containers.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot, but you can use a volume and mount the volume on both containers the problem is how you are going to copy the files from the image to the volume the first time, but it can be solved with some fantasy.

Comment: @Marco, seems like the first-time copy is automatic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950490/can-you-mount-a-directory-from-a-image-into-another-container#72950661).