# Can you mount a directory from a image into another container

Tags: docker

Is it currently possible with docker to do something like this conceptually?

```
docker run --mount type=xxx,image=imageX,subdir=/somedir,dst=/mnt-here imageY ...
```

I understand this can be done during at docker build time with `COPY --from=....`, however, in my use-case it would only really be beneficial if it can be done at container creation time.

Answer (score 1):

The only things it's possible to mount into a container  [arbitrary host directories](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), [tmpfs directories](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/), and [Docker named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  You can make a named volume [use anything you could mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options) with the Linux **mount**(8) command.  Potentially you can install additional [volume drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver) to mount other things.  But these are all of the possible options.

None of these options allow you to mount image or container content into a different container.  The `COPY --from=other-image` syntax you suggest is probably the best approach here.

If you really absolutely needed it in a volume, one option is to create a volume yourself, copy the content from the source image, and then mount that into the destination image.

```bash
docker volume create some-volume

# Since the volume is empty, mounting it into the container will
# copy the contents from the image into the volume.  This only happens
# with native Docker volumes and only if the volume is totally empty.
# Docker will never modify the contents of this volume after this.

# Create an empty temporary container to set up the volume
docker run -v some-volume:/somedir --rm some-image /bin/true

# Now you can mount the volume into the actual container
docker run -v some-volume:/mnt-here ...
```